# Google Drive file.update with 2 legged oauth returns ok but doesn't work as expected

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I have a service account made in console.developers.google.com and I've added the client ID of said service into admin.google.com for my domain wide delegation under Advanced settings > Authentication > Manage OAuth client access.

Using the [Google Nodejs api client](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) and [Google Nodejs auth library](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs), I have then created a jwt client using:

```
const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
        key.client_email,
        null,
        key.private_key,
        [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata'
        ],
        'user@domain.com'
);
```

and with

```
const google = require('googleapis');
const sheets = google.sheets('v4');
const drive = google.drive('v3');
```

I've run

```
async.waterfall(
    [
        (callback) => {
            sheets.spreadsheets.create(
                {
                    auth: jwtClient,
                    resource: {
                        properties: {
                            title: 'Testing'
                        }
                    }
                },
                (err, spreadsheet) => {
                    console.log(spreadsheet);
                    callback(err, spreadsheet.spreadsheetId)
                }
            )
        },
        (spreadsheetId, callback) => {
            drive.files.update(
                {
                    auth: jwtClient,
                    fileId: spreadsheetId,
                    resource: {
                        addParents: config.folder
                    }
                },
                (err, file) => {
                    console.log(file);
                    callback(err, file);
                }
            )
        }
    ],
    (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(400).send({ error: err.toString() });
        } else {
            res.status(200).send("It lives!");
        }
    }
);
```

My response from the second call for file.update returns 200 and a response of the file:

```
{ kind: 'drive#file',
  id: '<id-here>',
  name: 'Testing',
  mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' }
```

But strangely... the `addParents` are not reflected in the details of the file on the Drive webapp.

Any ideas. I'm in contact with Google apis support and haven't gotten anywhere in about a week. Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `addParents` is a query parameter, not a field in the Files resource. As such, it should be specified as a peer of `fileId`:

```
drive.files.update(
    {
        auth: jwtClient,
        fileId: spreadsheetId,
        addParents: config.folder
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! This was my issue. Super appreciate the help!

Comment: As per [Stack Overflow guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please accept the answer if it is correct.

Comment: Whoops, thought I did when I commented. Sorry!

Comment: See [my issue on the respective GitHub repo](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/604#event-1516605364) for more help!